# hostPath PersistentVolume and spec.capacity.storage attribute

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm running a single master/node Kubernetes in a Virtual Machine, using `hostPath` as a persistent volume for a deployed Postgres database.

My `PersistentVolume` has the following configs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: postgres
  labels:
    type: local
  name: postgres-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/postgres
```

*Also, I have a `PersistentVolumeClaim` currently bounded to that volume, requesting all the capacity (`spec.resources.requests.storage: 1Gi`*).

Recently, the Postgres database exceeded the `spec.capacity.storage` in size, however, without causing any problems:

```
$ du -hs /data/postgres # Powers of 1024
1.2G    /data/postgres 

$ du -hs /data/postgres --si # Powers of 1000
1.3G    /data/postgres
```

**My question is:**

- The [`spec.capacity.storage`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#capacity) really matters when using a `hostPath`
  volume, or the volume is in fact caped by the underlying partition
  size?
- What should happen when the volume usage exceeds his `capacity`? (i.e., how Kubernetes will handle this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @wongma7 on the Kubernetes GitHub page:

> this is working as intended, kube can't/won't enforce the capacity of
>   PVs, the capacity field on PVs is just a label. It's up to the
>   "administrator" i.e. the creator of the PV to label it accurately so
>   that when users create PVCs that needs >= X Gi, they get what they
>   want.

You can find the original discussion [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48701).

Also, it's covered in the official [Volume/Resources](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#resources) documentation:

> **There is no limit on how much space an `emptyDir` or `hostPath` volume can
>   consume**, and no isolation between Containers or between Pods.
>
> In the future, we expect that emptyDir and hostPath volumes will be
>   able to request a certain amount of space using a resource
>   specification, and to select the type of media to use, for clusters
>   that have several media types.

Comment: Oh, I see that...After further investigation, I even found `capacity` considerations for `hostPath` volumes in the [official docs](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#resources). _I took the liberty of editing your answer to add this information._